# The distance from a point in $l_\infty$ to $c_0$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

$l_\infty$ is the space of bounded sequences and $c_0$ is the space of sequences converge to $0$, is a closed subspace of $l_\infty$. I am trying to prove that for any $x \in l_\infty$, $\;d(x,c_0) = \displaystyle \limsup_{n\to \infty} |x_n|$.

---

*Progress*: I started with $d(x,c_0) = \inf_{y \in c_0} {d_\infty (x,y)} = \inf_{y \in c_0} \sup_{i \in N} |x_i - y_i|$, then I got stuck. Here we have $\limsup y_n = 0$, but I dont know how can I make use of that

Comment: I started with $d(x,c_0) = \inf_{y \in c_0} {d_\infty (x,y)} = \inf_{y \in c_0} Sup_{i \in N} |x_i - y_i|$, then I stucked. Here we have $\limsup y_n = 0$, but I dont know how can I make use of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any sequence $y\in c_0$ we have 
$$
\|x-y\|_\infty = \sup_n|x_n-y_n|\ge \limsup_{n\to\infty} |x_n-y_n|=\limsup_{n\to\infty} |x_n|
$$
This gives a lower bound on the distance.

To get the matching upper bound, let $y_n=x_n$ when $n\le N$, and $y_n=0$ otherwise. This is an element of $c_0$, and 
$$
\|x-y\|_\infty = \sup_{n>N}|x_n| \xrightarrow[N\to\infty]{} \limsup_{n\to\infty} |x_n| 
$$
where the last step uses the characterization of $\limsup$ as the limit of suprema of tail sequences.

Comment: Thanks, now I see it.